# Swift Combine return AnyPublisher<Void, Error> with FlatMap (POST Request)

Tags: ios, swift, post, swiftui, combine

I started using combine and it's really cool but currently I have no idea how to fix it. I want to make a POST Request using combine so I have to decode Data, create my request, send it and after that return an

```
AnyPublisher<Void, Error>
```

Currently my code looks like this:

```
func postData<T>(withURL urlRequest: URLRequest, object: T) -> AnyPublisher<Void, Error> where T: Encodable {

        return Just(object)
        .encode(encoder: JSONEncoder())
        .mapError {
            let error = self.classifyError($0)
            return error
        }
        .map { data -> URLRequest in
            var request = urlRequest
            //BUILD REQUEST
            return request
        }
        .flatMap { request in
            let dataTaskPublisher: AnyPublisher<URLSession.DataTaskPublisher.Output, URLSession.DataTaskPublisher.Failure> = URLSession.DataTaskPublisher(request: request, session: .shared)

            return dataTaskPublisher
            .tryMap { try self.throwErrorOrContinue(data: $0, basedOnResponse: $1) }
            .decode(type: T.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
            .mapError { return self.handle(error: $0, from: urlRequest, object: T.self) }
        }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
```

And he tells me:

```
Cannot convert return expression of type 'AnyPublisher<Publishers.FlatMap<_, Publishers.Map<Publishers.MapError<Publishers.Encode<Just<T>, JSONEncoder>, _>, URLRequest>>.Output, Publishers.FlatMap<_, Publishers.Map<Publishers.MapError<Publishers.Encode<Just<T>, JSONEncoder>, _>, URLRequest>>.Failure>' (aka 'AnyPublisher<_.Output, _>') 
to return type 'AnyPublisher<Void, Error>'
```

I tried some mapping but it didn't work and I have no idea what he wants from me. Maybe one of you knows the problem? Thanks :)

Comment: If you decode something, then you expect some output data, so your publisher cannot be AnyPublisher<Void, Error>, because Void means you don't expect data... so rethink your flow and what you expect.

Comment: So it's not possible to decode something to handle a possible error but return Void if it was successful? (With .map or something?)

Comment: @Godlike So you are decoding for the sole purpose of handling the error? You don't want the decoded result?

Comment: @Sweeper currently yes. I just want to do a POST Request and my answer should only be 200 OK. I can remove the decoding and write 
``return dataTaskPublisher
            .tryMap { try self.throwErrorOrContinue(data: $0, basedOnResponse: $1) }
}. eraseToAnyPublisher()``
But it doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always `map` to `Void`, which is an empty tuple:

```
return URLSession.DataTaskPublisher(request: request, session: .shared)
    .tryMap { try self.throwErrorOrContinue(data: $0, basedOnResponse: $1) }
    .decode(type: T.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
    .mapError { return self.handle(error: $0, from: urlRequest, object: T.self) }
    .map { _ in return () }
```

Also `T` should be constrained to `Decodable`.

But really though, I think `postData` should return `AnyPublisher<T, Error>`. What to do with the data got from the server should be decided by the caller of `postData`. Therefore, you should change the return type of `postData` instead. For example, if the caller wants to ignore the result, it could do:

```
Publishers.IgnoreOutput(upstream: postData(...))
```

This creates a `Publisher` with `Never`, rather than `Void`, as its `Output`. The publisher will only produce errors.

Comment: Hmm yeah sounds better. Thanks. But .map { _ in return () } doesn't seem to work. 

``Cannot convert return expression of type 'AnyPublisher<Publishers.FlatMap<_, Publishers.Map<Publishers.MapError<Publishers.Encode<Just<T>, JSONEncoder>, _>, URLRequest>>.Output, Publishers.FlatMap<_, Publishers.Map<Publishers.MapError<Publishers.Encode<Just<T>, JSONEncoder>, _>, URLRequest>>.Failure>' (aka 'AnyPublisher<_.Output, _>') to return type 'AnyPublisher<Void, Error>'``

I think I will change it as you suggested. But I am curios why .map isn't working :D

Comment: @Godlike Works on my machine though... Note that the `flatMap` closure should have only one `return` statement. You shouldn't declare a `let dataTaskPublisher` because that will disable the type inference there. Also, what version of Xcode are you using? Mine is 11.7.

Comment: I was on 11.6 but updated to 11.7. and still didn't work. So I was curious and noticed that he has a problem with my flatMap. Now I make the encoding and building the request before calling this function and it works. 

But I am still curious why it didn't work with a flatMap.